# print jsonfile key that it's value is selected by input

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have following codes and problems , Any idea would help. Thanks...

**Nouns.json :**

```
{
"hello":["hi","hello"],
"beautiful":["pretty","lovely","handsome","attractive","gorgeous","beautiful"],
"brave":["fearless","daring","valiant","valorous","brave"],
"big":["huge","large","big"]
}
```

**Python file :** this code would find word synonyms from json file and prints them

```
import random
import json

def allnouns(xinput):
    data = json.load(open('Nouns.json'))
    h = ''
    items = []
    T = False
    for k in data.keys():
        if k == xinput:
            T = True
    if T == True:
        for item in data[xinput]:
            items.append(item)
        h = random.choice(items)
    else:
        for k in data.keys():
            d = list(data.values())
            ost = " ".join(' '.join(x) for x in d)
            if xinput in ost:
                j = ost.split()
                for item in j:
                    if item == xinput :
                        h = k
                        break
                    else:
                        pass
            else :
                h = xinput

    print(h)
xinput = input(' input : ')
allnouns(xinput)
```

**Example:**

```
example for input = one of keys :

>> xinput = 'hello' >> hello
>> 'hi' or 'hello' >> hi

example for input = one of values :

>> xinput = 'pretty' >> pretty
>> it should print it's key (beautiful) but it prints the first key (hello) >> hello
```

Problem is the last line of example

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks massively over-complicated. Why not do something like:

```
import json

def allnouns(xinput):
    nouns = json.load(open('Nouns.json'))
    for key, synonyms in nouns.items():
        if xinput in synonyms:
            print(key)
            return;

xinput = input(' input : ')
allnouns(xinput)
```

Comment: Another reason why this answer is a big improvement; all the names are very clear, which makes it much easier to read. I think it would help you(and anyone reading your code) if you used more descriptive variable names, instead of single letters.

Comment: im so sorry , i dont know how to script i just search and attach things!!!! you saved me with this code :)))

Comment: You should take the time to try to understand what each line is doing so you can avoid creating spaghetti code like in your original question